# Replace Symbol in Certain Pattern

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wrote a code like this in order to find pattern. In descriptions sometime "." will appear between numbers and text, for example, " 0.5 text book and pen.whatever." or "I love fried chicken and burger .65 mm."
I wanna replace "."between text but not numbers.

```
Dim FindPeriodIndex As Integer
Do While FindPeriodIndex = InStr(Description, Chr(46)) <> 0

    If IsNumeric(Mid(Description, FindPeriodIndex - 1, 1)) = False Or   IsNumeric(Mid(Description, FindPeriodIndex + 1, 1)) = False Then
        Description = SuperReplace(Description, Chr(46), " ")
    End If
 Loop
```

Superreplace is a function that I created, it's similiar to replace function but can replace an array. this doesn't matter in my question. The code that I create doesn't really work,could anyone give a better idea on why it's not working? Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim FindPeriodIndex As Integer
Do While FindPeriodIndex = InStr(Description, Chr(46)) <> 0

    If IsNumeric(Mid(Description, FindPeriodIndex - 1, FindPeriodIndex)) = False Or   IsNumeric(Mid(Description, FindPeriodIndex, FindPeriodIndex + 1)) = False Then
        Description = SuperReplace(Description, Chr(46), " ")
    End If
 Loop
```